# Prevent Yesod from generating client_session_key.aes file

Tags: haskell, yesod

When I launch my Yesod application, it generates a file named `client_session_key.aes`. I don't need it, because I use sessionless authentication. Can I stop Yesod generating this file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Yesod documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.33/docs/Yesod-Core.html#v:makeSessionBackend) says that the `makeSessionBackend` method by default "uses clientsession with a 2 hour timeout", and that "returning `Nothing` disables sessions". So the solution is to override that method and return `Nothing`:

```
instance Yesod App where
    makeSessionBackend _ = return Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment or delete this code from your `Foundation.hs` file:

```
makeSessionBackend _ = Just <$> defaultClientSessionBackend
    120    -- timeout in minutes
    "config/client_session_key.aes"
```

And do `stack build`.